# Select statement into decode function

Tags: sql, oracle10g

so I am writing a select query using a decode function, and set the result into a variable.

The thing is, when there is no lines, I always got no result error.

I tried decode with the value, and counting, but no results.

```
SELECT decode(count(id), 0, (select id from t_table where intitule = '?' and id_type =  93), id) into v_id
      from t_table where intitule = null
      group by id;


SELECT decode(id, null, (select id from t_table where intitule = '?' and id_type =  93), id) into v_id
      from t_table where intitule = null
      group by id;
```

But, as there is no line to decode, it doesn't work.

So, my query, must get an id, into v_id, where intitule = a value, else it bring back a default value that exist into t_table.

And as I alwys got 0 lines, I raise an no result found error.

So for example, I got into t_table those three lines

```
id | intitule | id_type

1  | ?        | 5
2  | electricien | 5
3  | mécanicien | 4
```

I will have a where I did'nt specify intitule, so `intitule = null`

So this bring back 0 lines.

But I know its the id_type, so if I do not found any lines (that is the case), I bring back the default value(?) for the id_type that I know (5).

So, in the end, I must have  `1` into `v_id`.

But if I have `intitule = 'electricien'`, so I will get `2` into `v_id`.

Is that better?

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Could you give some sample data and a desired result? I for one am having trouble (no pun intended) decoding the question.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I edit my question. I hope it's clearer to understand.

Comment: `intitule = null` never works, use `intitule is null`

Comment: @ammoQ yes, and the answer must deal with two possible situations intitule = 'value' or intitule is null. But it seems the  answer from thorsten will fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, there is more than one flaw in what you are doing.

First of all `where intitule = null` will never work. NULL doesn't equal anything, so = doesn't work with it. This must be `where intitule is null` instead.

But then, you want to select one row. So why do you group by ID? To group by ID means: get one record per ID. This is not at all what you want. You want *one* ID back.

It seems, you consider intitule to be unique? Then simply select the ID for the intitule wanted. If I understand it correctly, there is no record where intitule is null, right? You only want to select a particular record if no intitule is given to look for. So use OR in your where clause: Either intitule is given and must match OR it is not given and intitule must match '?' and id_type must be 93.

```
select id
into v_id
from t_table 
where intitule = vi_intitule
or (vi_intitule is null and intitule = '?' and id_type =  93);
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems it works. One question for my knowledge : What does the `:` after the variable mean?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion; the colon shouldn't be there. It is used in Oracle for variables in SQL. As you are in PL/SQL, the variables must not have a colon. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT 
   decode
   (
      select count(id) from t_table where id= e.id group by id, 
      0, 
      (select id from t_table where intitule = '?' and id_type =  93), 
      id
   ) 
   into v_id
FROM t_table e where intitule is null
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: `intitule = null` never works, use `intitule is null`